# WPF: Programmatically add label at specific Point

Tags: wpf, label

So i have `Circle` that i want to add simple `Label` at specific `Point`.

So i have this `Grid` that the Circle licate inside:

```
Grid gridCircleProgressBar;
```

And my Point where i want to create my `Label`

```
Point point;
```

So is it possible to create simple `Label` at specific `Point` ?

Comment: in grid you need to add margins to label, can you use canvas as container?

Comment: Why i need canvas  ?

Comment: Because a Canvas is the only built-in panel where you can explicitly position child elements by using coordinates. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `Margin` of the `Label`:

```
Point point = new Point(10, 50);
label.Margin = new Thickness(point.X, point.Y, 0, 0);
```

---

```
<Grid x:Name="gridCircleProgressBar" Background="Yellow"
              Width="100" Height="100">
    <Label x:Name="label" Padding="0">Label...</Label>
</Grid>
```

But you'd better use a `Canvas` if you really want absolute positioning:

```
<Canvas Background="Yellow" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Label x:Name="label" Padding="0">Label...</Label>
</Grid>
```

---

```
Canvas.SetLeft(label, point.X);
Canvas.SetTop(label, point.Y);
```

Comment: The label is not moving

Comment: The Canvas should be inside gridCircleProgressBar ? or maybe gridCircleProgressBar should be inside Canvas

Comment: The Label should be put inside the Canvas and the Grid should be removed.

Comment: But my Circle is inside this grid so what to do ?

Comment: Move the Circle to the Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add label dynamically. By setting margin you can adjust label on Circle. You can give grid name in xaml, and can assign dynamically like i have added.

```
        Label dynLabel = new Label();
        dynLabel.Name = "NewLabel";
        dynLabel.Content = "TEST";
        dynLabel.Width = 240;
        dynLabel.Height = 30;
        dynLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 21, 0, 0);

        Grid.SetRow(dynLabel, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(dynLabel, 0);
        MainGrid.Children.Add(dynLabel);
```